# Language selection with Umbraco and XSLT

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I am trying to show language flags on my Umbraco website (NL, ENG) with XSLT. My XSLT is only showing the flag if the page has a relationship with another page right now, but i also want to show the flags when there is no relationship with another page (this flag need to navigate to the index page of the selected language).

My idea was working with variables, but i did not know you could not change these with XSLT (kinda new to XSLT).

My question is: is there a way to always show the NL ENG flags even if the page does not has a relationship.

Here is my XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:param name="currentPage" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:variable name="smallCase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="upperCase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/../../*">

    <xsl:variable name="relations"  select="umbraco.library:GetRelatedNodesAsXml($currentPage/@id)//relation [@parentId =     $currentPage/@id]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nodeName" select="translate(@nodeName, $upperCase, $smallCase)" />

    <xsl:for-each select="$relations">
        <xsl:value-of select='@nodeName' />

        <xsl:variable name="url" select="umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@childId)" />

        <xsl:if test="contains($url, $nodeName)">
            <li><a href="{$url}" class="{$nodeName}"><xsl:value-of select='$nodeName' /></a></li>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my three structure looks like this (where Startpagina has a relation with Home and Algemeen has a relation with General :

[image: Tree view]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using the GetRelatedNodesAsXml method. I think you are taking a difficult approach here.
I am not sure if you want to display only the flag of the current language or both flags

This will display the flag of the current language:

```
<xsl:variable name="languageNode" select="$currentPage/ancestor::*[@level = '1']" />
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl($languageNode/@id)}" class="{$languageNode/@nodeName}">
 <xsl:value-of select='$languageNode/@nodeName' /></a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

If you want both flags, try this:

```
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="/root/*[@nodeType = 'add the nodeTypeID of your language items']">
<li>
      <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}" class="{@nodeName}">
     <xsl:value-of select='@nodeName' /></a>
     </li>    
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

In the seconde approach I use the @nodeType to filter out unwanted items from the first level of the content-tree. Make sure you use different document types for different types of content items.

I have not tested this, but it should get you close. 
Also open the umbraco.config file in the /app_data/ folder, it displays the XML-schema for your content. Makes it easier to create xpath queries.

Comment: I need to display both flags. I am using the GetRelatedNodesAsXml because i want to navigate to the related page. So if my "Algemeen" is related with "General" and the user is on the page "Algemeen" and clicks on the English flag he gets navigated to "General". If "Algemeen" does not have a related page and the user clicks on the English flag he gets navigated to /eng/index.aspx or something.